# Clearing the Android "Bluetooth Share" data cache programatically

Tags: android, caching, bluetooth, share

We have just managed to replicate an issue that a customer is reporting with our Android Tablet (4.4.2) and a Bluetooth device. They have reported that they are unable to pair our supplied bluetooth device with the our supplied tablet. To fix it they just rebooted the tablet.

In the office we have replicated this. Going to Settings->Bluetooth and clicking on the device in Available Devices doesnt do anything. If I power up another one of our devices, then I can pair with it without an issue.
Its only this one particular device thats causing the issue....which got me to thinking Android was caching this devices info somewhere and that cache was now out of date/corrupt somehow.

After a lot of googling I came across the tip of clearing the "Bluetooth Share" application data cache and this fixes this issue. However I need to do this automatically from code.

Has anyone come across this issue? And if so how have you managed to call this Clear Cache function from code?

Thanks!